# PostgreSQL how to get orders for day by hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which looks like

```
Order
OrderId
OrderStatus
OrderTime
```

I also have another table

```
OrderId
OrderLineId
OrderLineAmount
OrderLineCost
```

I am trying to get an average amount per hour between 2 dates I.e could be start and end of day, or start and end of week. 
So for example if two orders where placed at 9am and 9:30am at £50 each. Then I am trying to get:

```
20/07/2018 09:00:00 - 20/07/2018 10:00:00 
2 
100
```

If that makes sense?

I currently have this but not quite working the way I need

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as "number of orders",
sum(ol.quantity * ol.amount) as "line total",
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from "ordertimestamp") / 600 )) * 600) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as interval_alias
FROM "Order" as o
inner join "OrderLine" as ol on o.orderid = ol.orderid
GROUP BY interval_alias;
```

Any help would be awesome, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
create table ord (
  orderid int,
  orderstatus int,
  ordertime timestamp
);

insert into ord values (1, 1, '2018-07-20 09:10:00');
insert into ord values (2, 1, '2018-07-20 09:40:00');
insert into ord values (3, 1, '2018-07-20 10:15:00');

create table orderline (
  orderid int,
  orderlineid int,
  orderlineamount int,
  orderlinecost int
);

insert into orderline values (1, 100, 50, 40);
insert into orderline values (2, 100, 25, 40);
insert into orderline values (2, 100, 25, 40);
insert into orderline values (3, 10, 1234, 40);  

select
    date_trunc('hour', o.ordertime), 
    count(distinct o.orderid), 
    sum(l.orderlineamount)
  from ord o
  join orderline l on l.orderid = o.orderid
  group by date_trunc('hour', o.ordertime)
  order by date_trunc('hour', o.ordertime);
```

Result:

```
date_trunc                     count                 sum                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-07-20 09:00:00.0          2                     100                   
2018-07-20 10:00:00.0          1                     1234
```